# Retrieve list items from multiple lists with urls stored in an array

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint-2013

How do i get list items from different lists in SharePoint using javascript. Given that all my list are stored in an array. And I need to loop through the array and execute similar functions on each list.

```
function initializePage() {

listcollections.forEach(function (value, index) { // listcollections is the array that contains the list url for different lists

    var listtitle = value.listTitle;
    var siteUrl = value.siteURL;


    getItemsWithCaml(siteUrl, listtitle,
    function (camlItems) {


        var listItemEnumerator = camlItems.getEnumerator();
        while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {

            var EventsItem = new Events();
            var listItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();

            EventsItem.eventTitle = listItem.get_item('Title');
            EventsItem.eventDate = listItem.get_item('EventDate');
            EventsItem.eventId = listItem.get_id();
            EventsItem.eventSite = siteUrl;
            EventsItem.eventList = listtitle;

            EventsCollection.push(EventsItem);


        }
    },
        function (sender, args) {
            alert('An error occurred while retrieving list items:' + args.get_message());
        });       
})
```

};

```
function getItemsWithCaml(siteUrl, listtitle, header, success, error)
```

{

```
var hostWebContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);

var list = hostWebContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listtitle);

var caml = new SP.CamlQuery();

//Create the CAML that will return only items expiring today or later
caml.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'Expires\'/><Value Type=\'DateTime\'><Today /></Value></Geq></Where> </Query></View>");
var camlItems = list.getItems(caml);
hostWebContext.load(camlItems);
hostWebContext.executeQueryAsync(
        function () {

            success(camlItems);
        },
        error
    );
```

};

//need to execute certain functions to format each list item

// I am not able to retrieve all list items in a single variable to be able to display data from all lists together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example below, I create a JavaScript object named **ListDataCollection** that contain a property **Lists** that is an array of objects.

Each of those contain a **Url** property whit the url of the lists I want to get the content.

Then I loop trough the array of objects and call the Sharepoint REST api for each Url.

Each time a call is complete :

- I create a **Data** property on the current object with the data received
  by the ajax call to the REST api.
- I also update the current object **Completed** property to true.

Then I call a function named **ifAllCompleted** that check if all ajax calls are ended.

When all data is received, I log the word **Completed** on the browser console.

At this point, you have an array of objects. Each object contains the data of one Sharepoint list.

For example :

```
ListDataCollection.Lists[0].Data.d.results[0].Title
```

will contain the value of the **Title** Column of the first element in the first list.

If you want, you can merge all data in one array using the **concat** function in JavaScript.

Look at the 4 lines of code following the word **Completed**.

Hope this can help!

```
<script>
var ListDataCollection = {
    Lists:[{
        Url:"http://Url.Of.Your.Site.Collection/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List1')/Items",
        Completed:false
    },{
        Url:"http://Url.Of.Your.Site.Collection/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List2')/Items",
        Completed:false
    },{
        Url:"http://Url.Of.Your.Site.Collection/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List3')/Items",
        Completed:false
    }]
};

function ifAllCompleted() {
    for (var i=0;i<ListDataCollection.Lists.length;i++) {
        if (!ListDataCollection.Lists[i].Completed) {
            return false;
        }
    }   
    console.log('Completed');   
    var arrayOfAllData = ListDataCollection.Lists[0].Data.d.results;
    arrayOfAllData = arrayOfAllData.concat(ListDataCollection.Lists[1].Data.d.results);
    arrayOfAllData = arrayOfAllData.concat(ListDataCollection.Lists[2].Data.d.results);
    console.log('Total elements : ' + arrayOfAllData.length);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    for (var x=0;x<ListDataCollection.Lists.length;x++) {
        $.ajax({
            url:ListDataCollection.Lists[x].Url,
            indexValue:x,
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                ListDataCollection.Lists[this.indexValue].Data = data;
                ListDataCollection.Lists[this.indexValue].Completed = true;
                ifAllCompleted();
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                console.log('error');
            }
        });     
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! i did solve my problem by creating different functions for each list but my code looks crappy. I will try this out.

Comment: I used your method for a different problem i was facing. Works perfect! Thanks